# Setting up Eclipse and Glassfish offline

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I have a Glassfish 3.1 server set up running on my development machine, and I'm trying to write a Java application that uses the OpenMQ JMS server built into Glassfish. I'm using Eclipse EE 3.6 for development (and have to as the application I'm developing is a plug-in for a Eclipse framework application - no changing to NetBeans!).

The problem is that my development machine isn't connected to the internet, so I can't download the Glassfish adapter from within Eclipse as told to do so in pretty much every online tutorial and guide I've found.

Is it possible to download the adapter on another computer, transfer it to the development machine, and install it into Eclipse 'offline'? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adapter is available as a eclipse plugin(it must be available, if it can be updated via eclipse plugin update site) you can just download and keep it @ eclipse_home/plugin folder and restart the eclipse.

Comment: Any idea where I might find the plugin? I've tried the plugins listed at http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios, putting both the 'features' and the plug-in jars what I believe was the right location, but to no avail.